# c# change the form title by the savefile name.extension

Tags: c#, rft

everytime i change a file such as a .rft or .txt i want it to display the name in the title for e.g `RFT Editor:docment.rft`

here the code i am using atm

```
this.Text = "RFT Editor:" + saveFileDialog1.FileName;
```

hope someone can help

Comment: Whats the issue with the existing code?

Comment: Do you mean Rich Text File? That's RTF. RFT is Rational Functional Tester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need this:

```
...
...

// Save clicked inside, not Cancel
if(saveFileDialog1.openDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // this.Text is same as only Text - in case of current class (matter of choice)
    Text = "RTF Editor: " + savefileDialog1.FileName;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is poorly worded. You don't describe how the result you are getting is different from what you'd like it to be.

I can only guess the problem is that `"RFT Editor:" + saveFileDialog1.FileName` gives you a file name with an entire path, and to get *"RFT Editor:docment.rft"* as in your example you'd need  `"RFT Editor:" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(saveFileDialog1.FileName)` instead.